# try:'spam'[2] except IndexError:print('exception') ==> why not 'a'?

Tags: python, try-except

I expected the following two lines of Python codes to return `a`, as that's what `'spam'[2]` is supposed to return; instead, I am getting no returns. Can someone explain this for me?

```
try:
    'spam'[2]            
except IndexError:
    print('exception')
```

Python returns blank. I expected the results will be the same as the result of 'spam'[2] without any try/except blocks.

Comment: What do you mean by `return`? There is no `return` nor a `print`, so this expression does nothing.

Comment: 'spam'[2] is returning 'a' but you are not using it anywhere

Comment: Are you running this in the Python shell? It should work ok there.

Comment: So, although 'spam'[2] returns 'a', when the same is enclosed in a try block, I need print or something else? tkausl, I have no idea how to "describe" Python showing the result, so I used the term "return", which is not return command in Python.

Comment: Thanks, Johnny Mopp; I realized that it works at Python Shell. I was using PyCharm, and it doesn't work in PyCharm. I am at a loss completely...